# Interpolation in Rails Route Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, resources, routes, helper

Is there any way of interpolating into a call to a route helper?

I have a partial in which I pass a resource (User, Gallery etc) as a local called `resource`. I need a link to edit the resource, but I need the link to be different for each resource:

For a user the link needs to use the helper `edit_user_path`, for Gallery it needs to use `edit_gallery_path` etc.

So I need a way to interpolate the resource name into the helper (Pseudo code):

`edit_{resource.name}_path`

Comment: If you are using Inherited Resources, you have the url helper `edit_resource_path(resource)` available (https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#url-helpers)

Comment: @MrYoshiji  Looks like the Gem's owner has deprecated it.

Comment: Arf, This gem brings so much black magic and confusing stuff, and now they deprecate methods without updating their doc!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can replace `edit_user_path` with `send("edit_user_path")`. Already verified in console.

Now you can interpolate the string inside.

Comment: Nicely done. Just to expand slightly on your answer:`send("edit_#{resource.class.to_s.underscore()}_path", resource)`.

Comment: I need to do that in a view, so I'm getting an `undefined method error`. Do you know on what class call send? In console I do `app.send..`

Comment: @cortex, this should be able to work in view as OP does. Also there is no class as the named path belongs to Rails app instance. If you still have problem you can post a new question with details.